# Java - Find within List<> using .stream

Tags: java, java-stream

I'm trying to use the .stream operator to find an object within a List<> but getting a syntax error I cant resolve despite following the examples I find on the net...hopefully someone can help with whatever I'm not understanding.

I set up the following as the object to be stored in a List<>:

```
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Setter;

@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
public class JelCodeMapping {
    private String jelCodeId;
    private String jelCodeName;
    private int network1;
    private int network2;
    private int network3;
}
```

Then instantiate a list (it gets populated elsewhere)

```
private List<JelCodeMapping> jelCodeMappings;
```

I then want to search for an object within the list which contains a particular value:

```
    private List<Integer> getNetworksForJelCode(String jelCode) {
        JelCodeMapping jelCodeMaping = jelCodeMappings.stream().filter(mapping -> mapping.getJelCodeId().equals(jelCode));

        List<Integer> jelCodeNetworks = new ArrayList<>();

//  other stuff happens here

        return jelCodeNetworks;
    }
```

but the line where I'm using the .stream() operator generates the following syntax error message:

```
Incompatible Types
Required: <packagePath>.JelCodeMapping
Found: java.util.stream.Stream   <packagePath>.jelCodeMapping
```

I'm fairly sure I'm following the examples I've found, but cant resolve the issue. What am I not understanding?

Thanks for any thoughts/insights

Comment: What type do you think `filter()` returns?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to add a terminal operation to the stream.

For example

```
JelCodeMapping jelCodeMaping = jelCodeMappings.stream()
    .filter(mapping -> mapping.getJelCodeId().equals(jelCode))
    .findFirst()
    .orElseThrow(() -> new RuntimeException(
        "JelCodeMapping not found: " + jelCode));
```

See also the documentation for [streams](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html) and in particular [filter](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#filter(java.util.function.Predicate)), [findFirst](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#findFirst()) or [findAny](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#findAny()).

The "Incompatible Types" error is because `filter(Predicate)` returns a `Stream`. The `Stream` can't be assigned to the `JelCodeMapping` variable.

The find methods return an optional and the `orElseThrow` methods will either return the optional value if present or throw the exception.

Comment: Excellent, thanks William...most helpful!

Answer (score 1):

William's answer is to the point.

With Java 9 and above, you can also use `dropWhile` and `findFirst` (This is an equivalent alternative).

```
jelCodeMappingList.stream().dropWhile(jelCodeMapping -> !jelCodeMapping.equals("ID")).findFirst()
```

If the list might have multiple elements with same ID, you can use

```
jelCodeMappingList.stream().collect(Collectors.filtering(jelCodeMapping -> jelCodeMapping.getJelCodeId().equals("ID"),Collectors.toList()));
```

which returns you a list of JelCodeMapping with same ID.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need a `collect()`, and make sure that there is someone whose `jelCodeId` equals with `jelCode` in `jelCodeMappings`;

```
List<JelCodeMapping> jelCodeMaping =
                jelCodeMappings.stream()
                    .filter(mapping -> mapping.getJelCodeId().equals(jelCode))
                    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```